# How to access JMETER controllers variable from JSR223 Processor (groovy)?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I would like to get the While Loop index counter, ${__jm__WC__idx} , in my JSR223 PreProcessor groovy script.
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller

I have a While Loop controller named WC and in this controller I have JSR223 PreProcessor.

Below is what I've tried. Not sure how I cat read ${__jm__WC__idx} value.
log.info('While Controller index: ' + vars.get('${__jm__WC__idx}'))

Expecting to get While Counter index value 0,1,n but got null.
Thanks

Comment: I end up using a ForEach Controller with a Counter for now.

Answer (score 2):

Use vars with a string parameter `__jm__WC__idx`:

```
vars.get("__jm__WC__idx")
```